# Ironpython tools for VS2010: how to debug python code with 'import'?

Tags: ironpython

I have installed an IronPython tools for VS2010 and all works fine. But if i try to use an 'import' statement outside 'hello world', for example:

```
import email
```

Iron python will fail to debug with error message like 'cannot import mime from email'. Any hints how to avoid such errors or ironpython tools for vs2010 currently can't hand any 'include' outside 'os'/'sys'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried IronPython tools for VS2010 but I guess your `sys.path` does not include path to the `email` module. Check there are `email` and `email.mime` modules and if not, add the path to them into `sys.path' manually.